# How bind TabControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, silverlight-4.0

xaml

```
<controls:TabControl x:Name="tabControlRoom" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
            <controls:TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controls:TabItem Header="{Binding name}">
                        <StackPanel Margin="10" Orientation="Horizontal">

                        </StackPanel>
                    </controls:TabItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:TabControl>
```

and code

```
m_roomContext.Load(m_roomContext.GetRoomQuery());
                tabControlRoom.DataContext = m_roomContext.Rooms;
```

when I open this page, then there is all the elements, but a second later I see only a white screen

**error:**

> load operation failed for query
>   'GetRoom'. Unable to cast object of
>   type 'Web.Room' to type
>   'System.Windows.Controls.TabItem'/'

Comment: hi, i've some problem recreating your code with this parameters d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height", anyway, where do you put the load of the tabs?

Comment: michele, no. this not problem. I update post.

Comment: What does m_roomContext.Load() exactly do, and what is the type of m_roomContext.Rooms? I'm guessing, but I think the fault lies in the code behind, not in the binding. You can see all the elements as long as the datacontext of the tab is null, but it blanks as soon as the cast fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create converter

```
public class SourceToTabItemsConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            try
            {
                var source = (IEnumerable)value;
                if (source != null)
                {
                    var controlTemplate = (ControlTemplate)parameter;

                    var tabItems = new List<TabItem>();

                    foreach (object item in source)
                    {
                        PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = item.GetType().GetProperties();

                        //тут мы выбираем, то поле которое будет Header. Вы должны сами вводить это значение.
                        var propertyInfo = propertyInfos.First(x => x.Name == "name");

                        string headerText = null;
                        if (propertyInfo != null)
                        {
                            object propValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null);
                            headerText = (propValue ?? string.Empty).ToString();
                        }

                        var tabItem = new TabItem
                                          {
                                              DataContext = item,
                                              Header = headerText,
                                              Content =
                                                  controlTemplate == null
                                                      ? item
                                                      : new ContentControl { Template = controlTemplate }
                                          };

                        tabItems.Add(tabItem);
                    }

                    return tabItems;
                }
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// ConvertBack method is not supported
        /// </summary>
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("ConvertBack method is not supported");
        }
```

Create ControlTemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyTabItemContentTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

And binding convert, controltemplate

```
<controls:TabControl  x:Name="tabControl"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=tabControl, 
                              Path=DataContext, 
                              Converter={StaticResource ConverterCollectionToTabItems}, 
                              ConverterParameter={StaticResource MyTabItemContentTemplate}}">
        </controls:TabControl>
```

taken from the blog [binding-tabcontrol](https://simplecod.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/binding-tabcontrol-%D0%B2-silverlight-4-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3-%E2%84%961/)

Answer (score 1):

When binding the TabControl there are two things you need to accomplish, one is the header content for the TabItem the other is the content for the selected TabItem, which is generally another user control.

The way have I've solved this in the past is to bind ItemsSource of the TabControl to a collection of view models, and to provide two data templates, one to supply the header content for the TabItem, an the other to supply the content for the selected TabItem, which maps to a view.

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ContentTemplate">
        <local:SampleView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TabControl 
        ItemsSource="{Binding SampleViewModels}" 
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ContentTemplate}"
        SelectedIndex="0"
        />
</Grid>
```